# Community Moderation Strike - The Return of the Arqade Mods

Tags: discussion, moderators

After nearly two months, [significant advancements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations) have been made between Stack Exchange and those who are/were leading the Community Moderation strike. For those who didn't know, on June 5th of this year, moderators and members of the various SE sites [began a strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) due to *mainly* how a policy in regards to how the moderation of AI content was implemented, and the policy itself. Like many other mods, us [Arqade moderators joined in](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16790/community-moderator-strike).

**On August 2nd 2023, adequate results were achieved between those leading the strike and Stack Exchange. With these satisfactory results, the mods of Arqade have decided to return to duty.**

For more information on the results of the negotiations, please see the first link above. But regardless...

### We are back!

Comment: Except for me mostly but that's because I'm out of town until Monday.

Comment: In the meantime we also reached 100,000 questions milestone :')

Comment: @pinckerman we are thinking we will do a post for that. I'm thinking instead of Screenshot of the Week next week, we instead do a "best of Arqade" post instead where users would posts their favorite questions asked on the site over the years, or possibly something else.

Comment: This means you'll start handling SotW posts on time, right? ...... right? ;)

Comment: @Wondercricket sorry but that wasn't apart of the strike negotiations :)

Comment: It's time for your new event!

Comment: After deciding to check in with how things are going here after I had to leave for a while, I did not expect *this* to be what I walk into; just wow! I don't know the full detail but I hope you're all picking up okay after what appears to have happened!

Answer (score 11):

For fun, I'd thought I share some of the things I personally witnessed on our site during the strike:

- At one point, we had close to, if not over 40 flags unhandled. Normally, we have *none*.
- Spam posts would linger for much longer lengths of time (they would eventually still get handled, but nowhere near as fast, and that's partially due to us mods ignoring them, and also with [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) being disabled).
- Review queues slowly filled up. Usually our queues are kept pretty tidy and empty, but during the strike there were times where the review queue icon would have the red indicator dot appear on it, which is rare for our site.
- A number of close vote review items aged away from the queue during the strike leaving some (mostly) duplicate posts open. I would say normally this rarely happens because our community can usually handle them, but when they end up with one or two more votes awaiting for a period of time, a moderator would/could usually be the last voter to move the item out of the queue.  This wasn't happening though, and I've seen some comments on posts that have been reflagged for review already.
- I've read a number of other comments on posts saying something to the tone of "hopefully a moderator... but they are striking".  Well I'm glad to say that shouldn't be the case anymore!

Comment: Our "average flag handling time" went from something like 50 minutes to 4 days. Mind you, if you saw a flag handled in that time, chances are it was handled by one of the Community Management team.

Comment: Glad you are back!

Comment: @Robotnik do red flags automatically handled by Community also contribute to something being done for the purposes of that stat?

Comment: @Unionhawk I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is yes, auto-flags are also counted. It would be more work to code an exception, than to just deal with some slight inaccuracy in that 'flags handled avg' number

Answer (score 8):

ALSO

Some time in the past few days, we surpassed 100,000 (undeleted) questions.

[image: 100,011 questions]

Comment: Time to go on a deletion spree then! :P

Comment: It would be interesting to know how many of these have accepted answers, no accepted answers, and 0 answers.

Comment: @LoreFriendly Ask you and you shall receive: [Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/1773975)

Comment: We reached the milestone twice. We had 100,001 questions after that, one (unkown) was deleted and we came back to 100,000. I was there.