# What to do if a user keeps posting low-quality answers to questions?

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/305147/zeke-wei?tab=profile) has 1 reputation on multiple sites, and all of his questions have a negative score. His activity on this site consists of two answers, and while they answer the question, they are needlessly long and are written as poetry, not direct answers. One of these answers is on [one of my questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/403717/do-bows-do-double-damage-when-they-break/403725#403725) and has already obtained 5 downvotes (and no upvotes) during the four days of its existence. I don't want to waste my hard-earned reputation downvoting someone who won't even lose reputation from it. What do I do in this situation?

Comment: Note that you get the reputation points back if the post is deleted

Comment: They're slowly getting deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers seem to be AI-generated fluff. (Relevant Arqade Meta post: [Should we ban AI-generated content on Arqade?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16663/4797) | Relevant Meta SE post: [A user seems to be trolling many SE sites with AI-generated answers; what should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391584/162827)) The user's vague answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/403720/4797) about Skyrim doesn't seem to answer the question at all; it seems to be addressing another question.

I'd flag the answers as very low quality and downvote them. (As stated in the [comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16839/what-to-do-if-a-user-keeps-posting-low-quality-answers-to-questions#comment49308_16839), you get the rep back once the post is deleted.) Flagging an answer as very low quality will put it in the [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts), where users with the required rep can vote on whether to delete the answer. As of this edit, both of that user's answers: [[1]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/403720/4797) [[2]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/403721/4797) — have already been deleted.