# Do we want a banner regarding our policy on AI-generated answers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, artificial-intelligence

[Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera?cb=1)

2 simple questions here:

1. do we want a banner?
2. if so, what banner do we want?

Comment: I don't think the problem is widespread enough on Arqade to warrant a banner here, IMO. But if many people think the banner would be helpful then we should do it. :)

Comment: I'm ok with the banner, better safe than sorry

Answer (score 7):

#### Yes

We should have a banner to warn and inform users about our policy on AI-generated content. This should help discourage users from posting uncited or low-quality AI-generated content.

I don’t see any drawbacks to having such a banner. Some users might ignore it, but others might pay attention and reconsider posting a copypasted AI-generated answer they were about to. Even if the banner only deters a few users, it would still be helpful.

Users can also easily dismiss the banner, and it won’t show up again for logged-in users, so it shouldn’t be too annoying.

For now, we have to choose one of the two banner text options. I suggest we go with this one: `**Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools must be cited on Arqade. Learn more`.

This option is more aligned with the community consensus that we reached in the meta post: [Should we ban AI-generated content on Arqade?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16663/4797) When SE lets us customize the banner text, we can have another discussion about writing a banner text that better reflects our policy on AI-generated content.

Comment: This variant of the banner has been enabled. Note that [the help center article that denotes the site's policy on the matter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy) is mod-editable, and thus can be tweaked to better reflect this site's specific policy.